# Unfortunately app has stopped error eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I've created an application in eclipse and it was working fine and then suddenly it keeps giving me the error message 'unfortunately app has stopped' could anyone explain where my problem lies from my log cat report as i am new to this and dont really understand what the log cat means?

```
03-12 12:31:03.465: D/AndroidRuntime(4997): Shutting down VM
03-12 12:31:03.465: W/dalvikvm(4997): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416a8930)
03-12 12:31:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4997): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 12:31:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4997): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.softwaresearchapp/com.example.softwaresearchapp.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.softwaresearchapp/com.example.softwaresearchapp.SoftwareSearchActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
03-12 12:31:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4997):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-12 12:31:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4997):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-12 12:31:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4997):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-12 12:31:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4997):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-12 12:31:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4997):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-12 12:31:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4997):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-12 12:31:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4997):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-12 12:31:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4997):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 12:31:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4997):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-12 12:31:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4997):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-12 12:31:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4997):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-12 12:31:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4997):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-12 12:31:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4997): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.softwaresearchapp/com.example.softwaresearchapp.SoftwareSearchActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
03-12 12:31:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4997):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1618)
03-12 12:31:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4997):     at android.app.ActivityThread.resolveActivityInfo(ActivityThread.java:1993)
03-12 12:31:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4997):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:285)
03-12 12:31:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4997):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:749)
03-12 12:31:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4997):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
03-12 12:31:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4997):     at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:240)
03-12 12:31:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4997):     at com.example.softwaresearchapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
03-12 12:31:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4997):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-12 12:31:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4997):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-12 12:31:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4997):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-12 12:31:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4997):     ... 11 more
03-12 12:31:22.666: I/Process(4997): Sending signal. PID: 4997 SIG: 9`
```

Comment: did you read it? did you? log is asking you the question ... did you answer this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
3-12 12:31:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4997): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.softwaresearchapp/com.example.softwaresearchapp.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.softwaresearchapp/com.example.softwaresearchapp.SoftwareSearchActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Specifically: `Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.softwaresearchapp/com.example.softwaresearchapp.SoftwareSearchActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Well, have you?

Each activity in your app must be declared in the manifest file. I imagine the minimum information you would want to provide would be the `name` and `label` e.g.

```
<activity
        android:name=".SoftwareSearchActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_software_search"
 />
```

Comment: I think i have i've got the line <activity android:name="com.example.softwaresearchapp.MainActivity....
is that the correct line of code?

Comment: Yes this line is correct but its not about MainActivity , read the logs error is because of com.example.softwaresearchapp.SoftwareSearchActivity.

Comment: No, that is for `MainActivity`. Each activity needs to be defined, so you need to create a similar block for `SoftwareSearchActivity`.

Answer (score 3):

your logcat clearly said

```
 Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.softwaresearchapp/com.example.softwaresearchapp.SoftwareSearchActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Add `SoftwareSearchActivity` into `manifest.xml` like

```
     <activity
        android:name="com.example.softwaresearchapp.SoftwareSearchActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="SoftwareSearch"
       />
```

Comment: Thanks sorry it was a silly spelling mistake in my manifest

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `ActivityNotFoundException`. Please check for Activity entry for `com.example.softwaresearchapp.SoftwareSearchActivity` in manifest file.